# combining Gauss and Stokes theorems leads to nonsense

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Gauss Theorem:
$$\int_S \vec{a} \, d\vec{S}=\int_V\operatorname{div}(\vec{a})\,dV$$

Stokes theorem:

$$\int_C \vec{a}\,d\vec{l}=\int_S\operatorname{curl}(\vec{a})\,d\vec{S}$$

Combining together:

$$\int_C \vec{a}\,d\vec{l}=\int_S \operatorname{curl}(\vec{a}) d\vec{S} = \int_V \operatorname{div}(\operatorname{curl}(\vec{a}))\,dV=0$$

since $\operatorname{div}(\operatorname{curl}(\vec{a}))=0$, whats wrong here?

Comment: Should you have $\vec{a}\cdot d\vec{S}$ instead of $\vec{a}\,d\vec{S}$, i.e. a dot product?

Answer (score 2):

This works only if $S$ is the boundary of $V$ and $C$ is the boundary of $S$.  But then $C = bbV$.  The boundary of a boundary is empty, and so $C$ was empty to begin with.  That is why the integral of any $1$-form over $C$ is $0$.

Comment: Viewed the other way around, if you start with a curve C which bounds an region S, there is no way that region S bounds a volume V.

Answer (score 1):

The surface in the Gauss theorem must be the boundary of the volume $V$. It's not the case with $S$ the surface related to the curve $C$.

Comment: Say we have any surface that intersects xy axis and the intersection could be considered as curve C. Then surface is then closed, why doesn't that work?

Comment: I don't mean close in a topological sense. I want to say that $E-S$ must have two connected components, in order to define the volume V..
I'm going to edit.
What do you mean by the xy axis ?

Comment: Oh I just realized that Stoke's theorem does not imply closed surface, but only capping surface to curve C. Thanks.