# Stokes' Theorem: line integrals around 2-faces of n-dimensional surface?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Suppose we have a convex polytope in $n$ dimensions and are trying to calculate the surface integral (over this polytope) of some scalar function $f:R^n \rightarrow R$. Suppose all edges and vertices are known, so, in particular, all 2-faces are known.

Can this integral be decomposed via Stokes' theorem into a sum of line integrals tracing paths around the 2-faces? I know the orientation has to be gotten right for integrating each face, but is there anything else I am missing that stops me from "jumping" from $n$ dimensions down to 2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "convex polytope in $n$ dimensions"? In particular, do you mean a two dimensional polytope?

Comment: And what do you mean by surface integral over this polytope? But, no, in general, a surface integral cannot be equated to a line integral on the boundary. In your case, most likely, these would all cancel, even if you could.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat: My example convex polytope is a hypersimplex (intersection of unit hypercube with hyperplane). I was trying to simplify the problem by assuming one application of Stokes' theorem, translating integral over the volume into integral over the surface/boundary.

Comment: @TedShifrin: See my response to Olivier regarding the specific shape. I was thinking that the surface can be decomposed into all of its component 2-faces, which I am able to describe combinatorically, and that each 2-face would have its own normal vector. Maybe I am missing something with how the normal vector would be defined for the surface integral?

Comment: You do not integrate a function on a surface, you integrate a differential 2-form.  So I really do not know what kind of question you are trying to ask.  Maybe you could give us a low dimensional example?  Say your polytope is a cube in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  What kind of thing are you trying to integrate?

Comment: @StevenGubkin: I am attempting to integrate over a volume by repeatedly applying Stokes' theorem. If my polytope were a cube, I would be attempting to integrate $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(\boldsymbol{x}) \rm{d}x_1 \rm{d}x_2 \rm{d}x_3$. My plan would be to apply Stokes' theorem once so I could integrate over the cube's boundary, and then find that integral by integrating over the faces. I am starting to sense that this is not a legitimate approach?

Comment: In this case, you would only be able to use Stoke's theorem if the 3-form $f(x)dx_1 \wedge dx_2 \wedge dx_3$ was exact i.e. if $f(x)$ were the divergence of some vector field.

Comment: You mean something like this? $\int_{volume} = \sum \int_{faces}$, then $\int_{face} = \sum \int_{edges}$, then ... ?

Comment: @StevenGubkin: $f$ is just a scalar field, that is, it maps $R^3 \rightarrow R$ in our example. Am I missing something as we convert from cube to surface?

Comment: You may also be interestedin this question:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603046/combining-gauss-and-stokes-theorems-leads-to-nonsense/603062#603062

Comment: $f$ is a scalar field, but to use stokes theorem, it must be the divergence of a vector field...

Comment: @Neal: I meant $\int_{volume} = \sum \int_{faces} = \sum \oint \mathrm{edges around each face}$

Comment: @StevenGubkin: Thanks for the link. That's what I was afraid of. More generally, can I have a one-dimensional divergence? E.g., $f(x)\boldsymbol{i} + 0 \boldsymbol{j} + 0 \boldsymbol{k}$.

Comment: @StevenGubkin: What about Neal's comment? Is it at least accurate to say $\int_{vol} = \sum \int_{faces}$, even if I can't then take the next step of using Stokes to get path integrals around the edges?

Comment: In the particular case of a volume integral of a function of 3 variables on a convex set, the answer is yes:  every such function is the divergence of a vector field, and you can then apply stokes theorem to see that the integral is equivalent to a surface integral over the boundary.  In general, life is not so simple.  If your region had nontrivial topology (say it was a torus, or a spherical shell), then this would no longer be true.

Comment: Even worse, if you were trying to convert a surface integral of a vector field into a line integral of a vector field in $\mathbb{R^3}$, you might not be able to do this at all, because even on a convex set, not every vector field is the curl of another vector field.  You at least need the original vector field to be divergence free.

Comment: It is kind of hard to understand this stuff when you have the grad/curl/div picture in your head (at least in my opinion):  I am really translating on the fly from how I am actually thinking, which is in differential forms.  I really recommend Ted Shifrin's book on the subject (He commented on this question, above!).  I am also planning on creating an online course about multivariable calculus in the near future, taking a differential forms approach.  It might be able to help you sort through all of this stuff.  Keep your eye on gratisU.org (nothing there now unfortunately)

Comment: @StevenGubkin: Aha! Thank you. That (and all the earlier stuff) was exactly what I needed to know. Can you post as an answer so I can give you credit? I will keep a lookout for the course.

Comment: @user1166202 no problem.  All in a nights work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the extend discussion (sorry!) in the above comments,

You cannot apply Stoke's theorem repeatedly to reduce the dimension of the region of integration over and over, because the boundary of the boundary of set is empty.  For example, the boundary of the solid ball is the sphere, but the sphere has no boundary, so we have to stop there.

Moreover, Stokes theorem says (most generally) that $$\int_R dw = \int_{bR} w$$  So if you are trying to rewrite $\int_R v$ as an integral over $bR$ by using stokes theorem, you will at least need to know that there is some $w$ so that $v = dw$, i.e.  $v$ must be an exact form.

I recommend learning multivariable calculus well:  to me that means with differential forms.  Ted Shifrin's book on the subject is excellent.  I also plan on producing an online multivariable calculus class which will cover differential forms in the near future (That is part of why I am patrolling the multivariable calculus tag on this site!).  That will be available on gratisU.org, which is currently blank.